# Соединение двух таблиц в одну НЕ по primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются две огромные таблицы с корявой структурой (чуть больше 105 000 записей в каждой **upd.** количество записей в каждой таблице разное). Явной связи между ними нет, сравнивать можно только по полю url (оно является primary key у обоих, но связать их как ключи не получится, потому что url одного сайта в таблицах в разном виде (www.asdasd.ru, http://asdasd.ru или asdasd.ru/address/params).

Также, у обоих таблиц есть поле title.

Задача. Перетащить значение title из одной таблицы в другую (с привязкой по url).

Опробованные решения.
Вторая таблица импортируется из csv. При создании записей второй таблицы вызывается триггер, который, используя регулярные выражения, сравнивает url у обоих таблиц и подставляет значение title из второй в первую таблицу. Очень долго.

Идеи.
Привести url к одинаковому виду, сделать их primary key. И... Какие действия дальше?

Может есть более умное решение?

**UPD.**
**Вариант 1**. Пробую привести url к виду domain.com.ru (используя сторонние скрипты и регулярные выражения *~3.5 часа* **upd.** **~10 часов**), затем выполнить запрос (неизвестно сколько времени займет)

```
UPDATE sites INNER JOIN titles on (sites.domain = titles.domain) SET sites.title = titles.title
```

**Вариант 2**. Тот же join, без приведения адресов к одному виду. Использовать LIKE вместо равенства. Неизвестно сколько времени займет. **UPD.** SELECT занял 3 минуты за 1000 строк. UPDATE выполняется уже ~5 часов (105К строк), т.к. прогресса не видно, непонятно сколько времени этой займет.

**UPD. Вариант 3**. По совету [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp). Эскпорт таблиц в csv (пара минут). Обходом regexp по url привел к одному виду (меньше минуты).

К сожалению количество строк в таблицах разное, поэтому объединить построчно два сортированных файла таблиц не получится.

Дальнейшие действия - Импорт таблиц обратно в базу (минут 10). Потом опять выполнять запрос из варианта 1 (предположительно >2 часов)

Не думаю, что я один с этим столкнулся, подскажите как задачу выполнить наиболее быстро (до 5 часов, одно ядро 1.80GHz)

**UPD. *РЕШЕНО.*** Использовал вариант 3, запрос из варианта 1 занял 15 секунд.

Comment: В вопросе уже присутствует разумное решение: привести url к единому виду, создать по ним индексы и обьединить простым запросом.

Comment: в оракл. для того чтоб не приводить урл к одному виду достаточно было бы создать индексы по функции. в мс скл хз можно ли так... хотя это решение мало чем отличается от предложеного выше. поддержу @out

Comment: @jmu, в postgres аналогично, просто индекс по функции создать.

Для первого варианта решения можно использовать временную таблицу.

Comment: Попахивает конечно порнографией но можно изворотится и попробцвать строковые функции http://www.mysql.ru/docs/maryan/  
В частности "SUBSTRING_INDEX" и "REPLACE" но это попахивает жосткой порнографией

Comment: 1. Вытащить обе таблицы в  файлы. Привести url к одинаковому виду. Отсортировать по URL. 

2. За один просмотр обоих файлов (ведь URL первичный ключ) создать третий файл с данными первого и заменой title из второго. 

3. Загрузить его в базу. 

--

Для слияния наверное свою программку придется написать. Если сделать в формате экспорта, то последующая загрузка в базу должна пройти быстро. 

100000 строк займут, ну скажем, 100 мегабайт. Их можно отсортировать в памяти меньше чем за минуту. Слияние (вместе с записью) займет не больше времени.

Comment: @avp идея отличная! Привел url к одному виду, отсортировал, а потом выяснилось, что во второй таблице (откуда надо взять значения) записей около 90К. И неизвестно, каких нет, то есть, просто построчно объединить файлы не получится, на выходе будет мешанина.

Comment: Я НЕ предлагал объединять **посторочно**. Надо делать *"слияние"* отсортированных файлов. 

Насколько я понимаю URL уникальны (для каждого файла). Тогда на каждом шаге сравниваем i-й url в первом с j-м во втором. (Файлы упорядочены по возрастанию url).

Вначале i=j=0; Если url[i] == url[j] берем title[j], формируем очередную запись 3-го файла, i++,j++. Если url[i] < url[j] формируем запись из данных[i] допустим с пустым title, i++. Если url[i] > url[j] просто j++. Детали IMHO очевидны.

В конце (за один проход файлов) получаем файл из записей первого файла с title (какие нашлись) из второго.

Comment: Получается 100000^2 операций сравнения.

Изначально я хотел просто воспользоваться утилитой parse.

В любом случае, спасибо, что помогли =)

Comment: @gridsane, откуда такая оценка ???

Сортировка N \* log N, слияние N. Смотрите на алгоритмы внимательней.

При сортировке рекомендую перемещать не сами записи а указатели на них, а сами данные записей загружать с диска  в память. 

Прямой доступ к данным **на диске** ***убивает*** производительность (чем грешат почти все СУБД).

Comment: @avp я, увы, не силен в алгоритмах, оценка в лоб, если для каждой записи из одного файла искать записи в другом.

Возможно предварительная сортировка ускорила бы слияние.

Объясню на пальцах, что я сделал.

1. Экспортировал обе таблицы в csv (меньше минуты каждая)

2. В текстовом редакторе прошелся по файлам регулярными выражениями и привел в порядок url, добавив дополнительный столбец domain, в котором хранятся url нужного мне вида (меньше 5 минут на оба файла)

3. Импортировал csv в новые таблицы (меньше 5 минут для обоих таблиц)

4. Выполнил запрос update с join по domain (16 секунд)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично. Я писал в комментариях о сортировке (слияние, **естественно**, с учетом сортировки. Это тоже написано в комментарии).

У Вас, как я понял, все получилось (тема закрыта) ? Тогда поздравляю.